# Iconic Woocomerce Bundled Products and Woocommerce Mix and Match plugins does not allow me to add products (No matches found)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, iconic

I am using these two plugins with woocommerce (3.0.6):

Bundled Products (2.0.0) [Iconic]
Mix and Match (1.1.7) [Woocommerce]
When I create a product with the custom types provided by those plugins, I cannot add products to a bundled. In the product search text box I only receive the message "No matchs found".

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to **version incompability**.

Iconic's **Bundle Product** plugin **only works with woocommerce 3+ since version 2.0.5**.

Woocommerce's **Mix and Match** plugin **only works  with woocommerce 3+ since version 1.2.0**.

So you need or to **update those plugins to their latest version** or to **downgrade woocommerce to a previous version** (ex.: 2.5).